# How can I fix the web-dev-server execution error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm so stuck. I need some help with anything.

My environment : WSL2

I execute webpack-dev-server

```
npm run dev
```

This is its log:

```
> lecture@1.0.0 dev /mnt/c/Users/J3SUNG/Desktop/react/React Study/lecture
> webpack-dev-server --hot

ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /dist/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /mnt/c/Users/J3SUNG/Desktop/react/React Study/lecture
@babel/preset-env: `DEBUG` option

Using targets:
{
  "chrome": "85",
  "ie": "11",
  "samsung": "12"
}

Using modules transform: auto

Using plugins:
  proposal-numeric-separator { "ie":"11" }
  proposal-logical-assignment-operators { "ie":"11", "samsung":"12" }
  proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator { "ie":"11", "samsung":"12" }
  proposal-optional-chaining { "ie":"11", "samsung":"12" }
  proposal-json-strings { "ie":"11" }
  proposal-optional-catch-binding { "ie":"11" }
  transform-parameters { "ie":"11" }
  proposal-async-generator-functions { "ie":"11" }
  proposal-object-rest-spread { "ie":"11" }
  transform-dotall-regex { "ie":"11" }
  proposal-unicode-property-regex { "ie":"11" }
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex { "ie":"11" }
  transform-async-to-generator { "ie":"11" }
  transform-exponentiation-operator { "ie":"11" }
  transform-template-literals { "ie":"11" }
  transform-literals { "ie":"11" }
  transform-function-name { "ie":"11" }
  transform-arrow-functions { "ie":"11" }
  transform-classes { "ie":"11" }
  transform-object-super { "ie":"11" }
  transform-shorthand-properties { "ie":"11" }
  transform-duplicate-keys { "ie":"11" }
  transform-computed-properties { "ie":"11" }
  transform-for-of { "ie":"11" }
  transform-sticky-regex { "ie":"11" }
  transform-unicode-escapes { "ie":"11" }
  transform-unicode-regex { "ie":"11" }
  transform-spread { "ie":"11" }
  transform-destructuring { "ie":"11" }
  transform-block-scoping { "ie":"11" }
  transform-typeof-symbol { "ie":"11" }
  transform-new-target { "ie":"11" }
  transform-regenerator { "ie":"11" }
  proposal-export-namespace-from { "ie":"11" }
  syntax-dynamic-import { "chrome":"85", "ie":"11", "samsung":"12" }
  syntax-top-level-await { "chrome":"85", "ie":"11", "samsung":"12" }

Using polyfills: No polyfills were added, since the `useBuiltIns` option was not set.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of /mnt/c/Users/J3SUNG/Desktop/react/React Study/lecture/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: asset app.js 1.31 MiB [emitted] (name: app)
runtime modules 460 bytes 4 modules
modules by path ./node_modules/ 1.23 MiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 36.1 KiB 10 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/ 6.04 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 60.5 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/scheduler/ 36.7 KiB 4 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-hot-loader/ 4.44 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/url/ 42.6 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/querystring/*.js 6.65 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react/ 79.6 KiB 2 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/react-dom/ 737 KiB 2 modules
modules by path ./*.jsx 7.23 KiB
  ./client.jsx 1.05 KiB [built] [code generated]
  ./WordRelay.jsx 6.18 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.1.3 compiled successfully in 22601 ms
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/DumpStack.log.tmp'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/hiberfil.sys'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/pagefile.sys'
Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/swapfile.sys'
```

So I tried to change the permission files using `sudo`,
but I get permission denied.

I confirm that I have permission through `ls -al`, but
this file's permission is displayed as `-????????`.

Please could you advise me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows likely doesn't like the fact you are storing/trying to write files in `C:/`. Since WSL doesn't always tie in correctly with Window's permission systems, even with `sudo` WSL likely isn't able to change the permissions of those files.

I'd recommend changing directories to somewhere you know your user has ownership of (e.g. your documents library or C:/users/yourusername), and trying again.

Comment: That's the thing -- where does one even specify that? I don't think either of us chose to store anything in the /mnt/c. As far as I'm concerned, it shouldn't be touching nor reading anything outside the project dir

Comment: Seems like it is a bug in WSL and how it talks to system files. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2779, https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1199. Nothing has been resolved yet unfortunately

Comment: Right, but I'm still not sure why webpack/webpack-dev-server is trying to read system files in the first place.

Comment: I'm also seeing that WSL2 might not have this issue (https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2809). Are you able to upgrade from 1?

Comment: It's a downgrade. WSL2 is much slower for my workflow.

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar issue and the solution that worked for me was clone (or create) my repository inside a WSL sub-directory from `HOME`, something like `~/workspace/React Study` instead of the mounted `C:\`.

This solution even improve a lot the performance using VS Code integration, specially when you're editing and saving files.

Comment: but what about other IDE?It looks like only VSCode is supported using this way.

Comment: Anuj Shrestha, VS Code has a "server" feature that enable remote coding, from one machine to another (in this case WSL2 is a Virtual one). I don't knot about other IDEs as I mainly use the VS Code nowadays, but I read a news saying that Visual Studio (the full one) now has this same integration with WSL2.

I guess that for other IDEs is up to them to implement this kind of feature, so my suggestion is to look for a roadmap or suggestion board where you can suggest and vote for this feature.